# Data base not working on tablet 3.1

Tags: android, sqlite, tablet

The app works in all devices except tablet. It's always giving error that I'm not closing database, but im sure that I'm closing everytime.  I open it like this

```
objDB = new dbManage(Activity.this);
        Items = objDB.select_Users();
        objDB.CloseDataBase();
```

and this is my select statement

```
public ArrayList<Items_OnlineUsers> select_Users() {

    ArrayList<Items_OnlineUsers> arrayList_ = new ArrayList<Items_OnlineUsers>();
    String qry = "select * from Online left outer join user_ on Online.u_id = user_.id_ ";
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.rawQuery(qry, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        Items_OnlineUsers u = new Items_OnlineUsers();

        u.setId_(cursor.getLong(0));
        u.setStatus_(cursor.getInt(1));
        u.setRand_(cursor.getLong(3));
        u.setName_(cursor.getString(4));

        arrayList_.add(u);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return arrayList_;

}
```

this is the logcat

```
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:283)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:116)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at com.ashabe.database.dbManage.add_new_Post(dbManage.java:1395)  
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at com.ashabe.utilityfunction.JsonDecoding.install_JSON_WallPost(JsonDecoding.java:3586)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at com.ashabe.www.LoginActivity$loginAsy.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:232)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at com.ashabe.www.LoginActivity$loginAsy.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-03 11:47:42.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): ... 4 more
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.ashabe.www/databases/ashabedb' 
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1980)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:977)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:734)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at com.ashabe.database.dbManage.open(dbManage.java:110)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at com.ashabe.database.dbManage.<init>(dbManage.java:95)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at com.ashabe.utilityfunction.JsonDecoding.install_JSON_WallPost(JsonDecoding.java:3585)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at com.ashabe.www.LoginActivity$loginAsy.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:232)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at com.ashabe.www.LoginActivity$loginAsy.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
02-03 11:47:43.464: E/SQLiteDatabase(1241): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
02-03 11:47:49.254: E/SqliteCursor.cpp(1241): Invalid statement in fillWindow()
```

and this is my database helper

```
public class dbManage {
   private dataB obj;
   protected static SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

   public dbManage(Context context) {
      obj = new dataB(context);

      try {
         open();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
     /**/
   }

   public void openDataBase(Context context) throws SQLException {
      sqlDB = obj.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public void open() throws SQLException {
      sqlDB = obj.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public void CloseDataBase() {
      obj.close();
      sqlDB.close();
   }
}
```

this is the database

```
public class dataB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String dBname = "xxx";
    static int v = 1;

    public dataB(Context context) {
        super(context, dBname, null, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a NPE in your asynctask which likely causes the close() to not to be called. The log says that it's install_JSON_WallPost() where the database was opened.

Comment: but iam sure that iam closing it

Comment: Your `sqlDB` is static so you're likely overwriting it with other references and orphaning unclosed database references.

Comment: can u till me why its working fine in any device but not on tablet

Comment: That particular error level log message is really just a noisy message with a stacktrace. The message was removed in JellyBean. It's not an exception thrown in the app and it's not the problem if your app doesn't work.